CMake Find Package Based on Target Architecture
I have a project which is cross-compiled for a Xilinx board using Vitis and the systems that are associated with that.  In order to cross compile, cmake has a cross-compilation file specified as:
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER aarch64-linux-gnu-g++)

This simply changes the name of the compiler used.  Per Xilinx/Vitis's internal machinations, the toolchain is globally configured by sourcing their bash scripts.  This may be important to note because it means that I am not necessarily specifying a sysroots path in my cmake cross-compilation file.
I would like to have an installed version of googletest that I would be able to link to regardless of the target architecture.  That is, I could have one version compiled for x86_64 and another located in /usr/local/lib and a special version, compiled for use in the cross-compilation using the cross-compilation toolchain, located in /my/favorite/path.
Using find_package, how would I target one version of googletest while cross compiling (e.g. /my/favorite/path/googletest/gtest_main.a), and the other version while compiling for my local machine (e.g., /usr/local/lib/gtest_main.a)?
I've played around with find_package(GTest PATHS ...), but I haven't met with a lot of success.  During the make install portion of googletest compilation there is a cmake directory created which does not appear to contain path-specific information, but I'm guessing is required as part of the find_package for GTest.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

You might be better off using a package manager like Conan which automatically rebuilds packages with your current toolchain

Normally, you have separate installation directory where you installed packages needed for cross-compile for a specific platform. When your perform this cross-compilation, you specify this installation directory via CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH variable, either in the command line or in the preset or in the toolchain file itself.

@AlanBirtles That's a brilliant program that I wish I had known existed earlier.  It's probably a bit too much for our team right now given the size of the project, but it seems like a useful tool to keep in my back pocket if the dependencies grow larger than a single library.

@Tsyvarev this worked, coupled with the inclusion of a couple of more missing directories.  This will likely be the solution moving forward: store a precompiled library copy at a known location (/opt/something_or_another) and then redirect the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH from within the toolchain specifier.  Please submit your answer if you'd like me to accept it.
